# Is there a way to pre-lookup related field models?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am exposing an API for a particular model, and want to serialize some of its related fields. These related fields are commonly repeated, and I don't want to have to do a numerous db queries for each related field serialization. Is there a simple way to pre-query all related instances, and then have have the RelatedField serializer look it up in a dictionary? Or maybe to specify from the ModelSerializer of the related field?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Django's standard [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) methods on your queryset.

On the view, use the `queryset` attribute, rather than the `model` shortcut.
For example...

```
class ExampleView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    queryset = Example.objects.select_related(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I wasn't aware of prefetch_related. Although it sounds like it is better to use it than to not, it still is not the most efficient implementation for my scenario. The reasons are: (1) it uses IN query which is multiple queries whereas my application can predict in one query which results it needs; and (2) most of the related fields use the same model class and it doesn't look like prefect_related is smart about that. Do you have any other suggestions for a more customized way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your use-case looks like, but if you need something custom that doesn't quite fit into the pre-provided generic views, then I'd suggest just writing the view methods explictly.

Comment: For example, as in the first section of tutorial part 3... http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views.html

Comment: OF course there's also no requirement that you actually use the serializers at all, if you've got some really custom case do the data-wrangling directly, and just return it in a `Response` object.  You'll still get the browseable API, permissions, auth etc., but you can be explicit about the precise view behavior.

Comment: @TomChristie Is this true for `get_queryset` method too?

Comment: @AndrésTorresMarroquín Yes.

Comment: @TomChristie When i add `prefetch_related` on a `modelviewset` , and try to `PATCH` on the M2M field, the response contains the values which were present before the request was made.. version - `3.3.2`